# How to view query that was used to create a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I create about 15 tables and create relationships and constraints among them using *Wizard* in **SQL Server 2012 express**

Now i want to see the *query*  that is used to create those tables including relationships and constraints. 
Can u provide help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Connect to your database using SQL Server Manager Studio
2. Right-click the table or the view in the Object Explorer panel
3. From the context menu choose Script Table as.../CREATE to.../< SomeDestination >
4. Choose a destination (a file, the clip board, etc.)

[image: Screenshot]

This would give you access to the DDL SQL that can be used to create this table.

Comment: I got the statement but i find it complex sir. It includes such as:
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Author](
 [AuthorId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [FirstName] [nvarchar](70) NOT NULL,
 [LastName] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AUTHOR] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [AuthorId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]`

Can we get _simple statement_ than this 'cause i don't know anything about: PAD_INDEX, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE,etc.

Comment: @KnockKnock That's true - SQL Management Studio makes all DB's assumptions explicit in this statement, so that if you were to re-create the object in another database, the result would come out exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways within SSMS to view the SQL statement (known as Data Definition Language, or DDL) used to create a table.

1. Right-click the table and  choose "Script Table as", "CREATE To" and choose your destination. This method is easiest if you just want to view the DDL for a single table quickly.
2. Right-click the database and choose "Tasks", "Generate Scripts" and follow the prompts. This method will generate DDL for all tables and many other database objects depending on your selection.

Either method will show constraints, indexes and metadata.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the table you want to get the details
2. Script table as
3. Create to
4. New query editor window/ Clipboard

If you select Clipboard, then open a new query window and paste it there.

That's it.

> Apart from that there is another thing you could do.
>
> If you want to see all constraints, keys, references stuff just click
>   on the table name in a query and Press **Alt + F1** It will list down more
>   technical details